# Comparing two objects angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one object that is like this

```
workingHours = [{
  endTime: 11:30,
  fixed: true,
  period: 'AM',
  startTime: 10:30,
  weekday: 'MONDAY'
},
{
  endTime: 10:30,
  fixed: true,
  period: 'AM',
  startTime: 08:20,
  weekday: 'FRIDAY'
}
}];
```

**And another object that looks like this**

```
workingHoursWeek = [{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'MONDAY',
  checked: false
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'TUESDAY',
  checked: false
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'WEDNESDAY',
  checked: false
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'THURSDAY',
  checked: false
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'FRIDAY',
  checked: false
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'SATURDAY',
  checked: false
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'SUNDAY',
  checked: false
}];
```

What i need is to compare this two objects and update **workingHoursWeek** to have all values from **workingHours**

At the end **workingHoursWeek** should look like this

```
workingHoursWeek = [{
  endTime: 11:30,
  fixed: true,
  period: 'AM',
  startTime: 10:30,
  weekday: 'MONDAY',
  checked: true
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'TUESDAY',
  checked: false
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'WEDNESDAY',
  checked: false
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'THURSDAY',
  checked: false
},
{
   endTime: 10:30,
  fixed: true,
  period: 'AM',
  startTime: 08:20,
  weekday: 'FRIDAY',
  checked: true
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'SATURDAY',
  checked: false
},
{
  endTime: null,
  fixed: false;
  period: 'AM';
  startTime: null;
  weekday: 'SUNDAY',
  checked: false
}];
```

Is there simple way to remap object properties to new object?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to concat both the objects into one?

Comment: Yes, thanks please

Comment: How do you want to compare these two objects?

Comment: I want to update object based from values on another obejct, please take a look my examples, you will say that now only MONDAY and FRIDAY have values and checked to true

Answer (score 1):

```
this.workingHoursWeek.forEach(day => {
   this.workingHours.forEach(newDay => {
      if (day.weekday === newDay.weekday) {
         day.endTime = newDay.endTime;
         // etc, update other times and check value to true
      }
   });
});
```

Or you can also use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) library

Npm Package https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash
For ex -

```
var a = {};
var b = {};

a.prop1 = 2;
a.prop2 = { prop3: 2 };

b.prop1 = 2;
b.prop2 = { prop3: 3 };

_.isEqual(a, b); // returns false if different
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, use forEach() loops:

```
this.workingHoursWeek.forEach(day => {
  this.workingHours.forEach(newDay => {
    if (day.weekday === newDay.weekday) {
      day.endTime = newDay.endTime;
      // etc, update other times and check value to true
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
this.workingHours.forEach(newDay => {
this.workingHoursWeek.find(function(element){
        if(element.weekday === newDay.weekday){
           element = newDay;
         }
     })
  })
```